# Do I need to re-import Susy to work with it in a child theme?

Tags: theme-development, child-theme, sass

I'm sure this is a question with a simple answer.

I am working on a [Storefront](https://woocommerce.com/storefront/) child theme. Storefront's stylesheet has been compiled using the [Susy](http://susydocs.oddbird.net) grid system - and I was hoping to inherit mixins etc. based on the parent's definitions, but all the Sass partials are present in the parent theme's Assets folder except for Susy (and Bourbon, which I'd like to use too).

Do I need to re-import/re-declare these libraries if I want to use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Sass is pre-compiled, you will need to import it in each stylesheet that you compile. This means that you will need to re-import it in your child theme stylesheet since it is independent of the parent theme stylesheet.